# Splitting rows containing ranges into both bounds

Tags: postgresql, range

Having a database containing tables containing :

```
rangeA
------------------------|
[400,800]               |
[350,2000]              |
[400,800]               |
[400,800]               |
[400,800]               |
[400,800]               |
[400,800]               |
[400,800]               |
[400,800]               |
[400,800]               |
```

**How would you drop that column in *each* table and replacing it with** :

```
lower|upper|
-----|-----|
  400|  800|
  350| 2000|
  400|  800|
  400|  800|
  400|  800|
  400|  800|
  400|  800|
  400|  800|
  400|  800|
  400|  800|
```

I already succeeded to retrieve the column and table names via :

```
select column_name, table_name
                    from DATABASE.information_schema.columns
                    where MYCONDITION) -- The condition is well chosen to retrieve only the column with the range
```

and of course when the rows are retrieved the function `lower` and `upper` can be used to retrieve the bounds

Comment: Why do you want to do that? What problem are you trying to solve with that?

Comment: I am trying to split the range into its upper and lower bounds in each of the tables containing a certain type because my database interface does not support serialization of that type in a range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of DDL statements that needs to be run for each table:

```
select * from t;
 x |     r      
---+------------
 1 | [400,800)
 2 | [350,2000)
(2 rows)

alter table t add l int;
ALTER TABLE

alter table t add u int;
ALTER TABLE

update t set l=lower(r), u=upper(r);
UPDATE 2

alter table t drop column r;
ALTER TABLE

select * from t;
 x |  l  |  u   
---+-----+------
 1 | 400 |  800
 2 | 350 | 2000
(2 rows)
```

If you need to run this for many tables you likely need to create a pl/pgsql procedure to generate and execute these DDL statements using system catalogs or INFORMATION_SCHEMA.

Here is a stored procedure example:

```
create or replace procedure mig_col () 
language plpgsql
as
$$
declare
 v_stmt text;
 v_t record;
begin
 for v_t in 
 (select pg_class.relname, pg_attribute.attname, pg_type.typname
  from pg_class 
  join pg_attribute on pg_class.oid = pg_attribute.attrelid 
  join pg_type on pg_attribute.atttypid = pg_type.oid and pg_type.typname='int4range')
 loop
  execute format('alter table %I add lrange int', v_t.relname);
  execute format('alter table %I add urange int', v_t.relname);
  execute format('update %I set lrange=lower(%I), urange=upper(%I)', 
                  v_t.relname, v_t.attname, v_t.attname);
  execute format('alter table %I drop column %I', v_t.relname, v_t.attname);
 end loop;
end;
$$;
```

That you can call by executing

```
CALL mig_col ()
```

Comment: Thank you, I was looking for a more automated version of it with an EXECUTE STATEMENT

Comment: I have added an example which assumes that the data type to be migrated is `int4range` and that the new column names are `lrange` and `urange`.

Answer (score 0):

```
create or replace function range_splitter (
    col_name text
    ,table_name text
    )
returns void as $$

begin
    EXECUTE format('alter table %s add column r_lower int, add column r_upper int;', table_name);
    EXECUTE format('update %s set r_lower = lower(%s),r_upper=upper(%s);', table_name, col_name, col_name);
    EXECUTE format('alter table %s drop column %s;', table_name, col_name); --optional
    RAISE NOTICE 'Table %s is altered', table_name;
end;$$
```

You may call it,

```
select range_splitter(column_name
      ,table_name)
from mydb.information_schema.columns
where data_type in ('int4range') -- you may add another range type here if you have;
```